# Creating a list/removing a row from a list if a string exist in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d list of strings in the form

```
data = [['DAL', "Luna's", 'Dallas', 'TX', '75235-3013', 'US', 40162.0, 'CFSAN', 'Pesticides and Chemical Contaminants'],
        ['DAL', "Luna's", 'Dallas', 'TX', '75235-3013', 'US', 41033.0, 'CFSAN', 'Foodborne Hazards']]
```

If a row in my list contains the characters "Food", such as in this case Foodborne Hazards, I want it to be eliminated from the list. This could be either by removing the row from the list or by creating a new list if it does not contain "Food".

I tried doing list the list comprehension below, but it did not work.

```
filtered_data = [[data[i,j] for j in range(len(data[0]))] for i in range(len(data)) if 'Food' in data[i,:]]
```

Could someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Pretty sure you want it *eliminated* from the list.

Comment: @DanHydar oops. Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `filter`. Comprehensions could do the same trick but I find that `map/filter/reduce` always make easier to read code:

```
def my_food_filter(inner_list):
    return not any(['Food' in str(p) for p in inner_list])

foodless_list = filter(my_food_filter, data)
```

Comment: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @OhadtheLad hey, nice catch, i reversed the params to filter. Try again, yea? That's the result of "coding" straight to SO.

Comment: @smassey foodless_list never gets declared. Is it because something should be passed into my_food_filter on the last line? Also, what exactly is happening with the return not? I have never seen it before. Thanks

Comment: @Jstuff foodless_list gets declared, maybe check your indentation? should be aligned with the `my_food_filter` (not inside the block of the def). the filter function expects 2 params: a single param function and an iterable. for each item of the iterable it calls the `single param func`. If the func returns false the item is discarded, otherwise not. the return not any([]) simply means that all the conditions evaluated to false. `any(X)` => return true if any item in X is true. `not any(x)` => return true if no items in the list are true (ie: they're all false).

Comment: @smassey youre right my_food_filter was defined but it was full of locations in memory. I'm not sure why but I ended up using your function and not using filter. I simply just did a for loop through my data then passed that into your function. If the function returned False I appended to a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[y for y in x if 'Food' not in str(y)] for x in data]
```

Input : data
Output :

```
[['DAL', "Luna's", 'Dallas', 'TX', '75235-3013', 'US', 40162.0, 'CFSAN', 'Pesticides and Chemical Contaminants'], ['DAL', "Luna's", 'Dallas', 'TX', '75235-3013', 'US', 41033.0, 'CFSAN']]
```

if you want to delete the list contains 'Food', try this :

```
[x for x in data if 'Food' not in str(x)]
```

Output :

```
[['DAL', "Luna's", 'Dallas', 'TX', '75235-3013', 'US', 40162.0, 'CFSAN', 'Pesticides and Chemical Contaminants']]
```

Comment: I want it to delete remove the entire string if the string exist in any column in the string. I tried your method and it only deleted the column of the string which contains 'Food'

Comment: The end result of the above list would be ['DAL', "Luna's", 'Dallas', 'TX', '75235-3013', 'US', 40162.0, 'CFSAN', 'Pesticides and Chemical Contaminants']

Comment: In this case `[[x for x in data if 'Food' not in str(x)]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
thelist[:] = [x for x in thelist if 'Food' not in str(x)]
```

u may use this while u iterate over the list - u'd never get out of index error

adding info for two nested lists- your case :

```
for singlelist in data:
    singlelist[:] = [x for x in singlelist if 'Food' not in str(x)]
print data
```